# How to pass JSON Web Tokens to different web pages after successful login?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I have a set of web pages that makes use of some APIs that need JWT as a header for authentication. This JWT is generated after success login. What would be the most appropriate way of sending jwt from one page to another after a successful login?

Comment: Store your jwt token into Local Storage after a successful login, and then you can use it in the page you need jwt token.

Comment: I can do that but many answers and websites claim that this is insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these to store JWTs:

1. HTML5 Web Storage (localStorage or sessionStorage)
2. Cookies

As [explained in this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) store JWT in cookies for web applications, because of the additional security they provide.

> What would be the most appropriate way of sending jwt from one page to another after a successful login?

Retrieve token from cookie/web storage in another page.